# How a print a particular thing for once in loop

Tags: python, loops

```py
name = 'kar'
for i in range(5):
      if name=='kar':
            print('name')
            print(i)
```

the above code will print **name** for 5 times. How can make it print **name** for once...and the rest of things will be printed according to the loop. Thanks!

Comment: If you do not to print "name" more than once, it would be a good start to remove it from the loop.  Loops serve to help you execute code more than once.

Comment: see the code again...i did some mistake while typing it...

Answer (score 0):

It’s difficult to understand what you want when comparing what you say to what your code says, but did you mean this?

```
name = 'kar'
for i in range(5):
    if i == 0:
        print('name')  # or print(name)
    print(i)
```

Comment: May be more natural to use `if i == 0`, for the first iteration.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I *did* mean that honest!

Answer (score 0):

```
name='kar'
times=0
for i in range(5):
    if times==0:
        times+=1
        print(i,name,'name') # str('name') or the variable name='kar' . whatever u want
    else:
        print(i)
```